# How to force Firemonkey to use a DirectX 9 context in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, directx, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

The main TForm3D window of Firemonkey application in Delphi X3 has a `Context:TContext3D` which gives me access to the current device used.
In my case with Windows7 64, it always shows a `TDX10Context` object from `FMX.Context.DX10.pas`.

I have not visibility to create new instance from `TDX9Context` class from FMX.Context.DX9.pas just to see the ancestor `TCustomDX9Context`.

I found the `TContextManager` class that collect the registerd 3D contexts in a strict private `TList` :( , this is the only class that can call the constructor...

```
{ Don't call contructor directly from TContext - only using TContextManager class }
constructor CreateFromWindow(const AParent: TFmxHandle; const AWidth, AHeight: Integer;`
```

They call `TContextManager` to get a context when creating new forms, then a readonly property `TContextManager.DefaultContextClass` is used.

There is no way I can find access to contexts other than `DefaultContextClass`.

Comment: From a comment on your G+ [post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107332916729762772829/posts/VKvvLHwdYUc): [GlobalUseDX10](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Types.GlobalUseDX10) := False;

Comment: Yes! :) That was unexpectedly easy and magical! it works! This line of code must be before application.initialize!

Comment: I'm a newbie here, I don't know if should answer my own question? :-/

Comment: Yes, if you find a good answer please post it to your own question. It might be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record:

Put the following line in your project file:

```
GlobalUseDX10 := False;  <<-- add this.
Application.Initialize;  <<-- just before this line.
```

Comment: Thanks, The trick works perfectly. We should also thanks g+ user: Sergionn Rad.

Comment: note there are other useful GlobalUseXX too in FMX.Types unit

Comment: btw, documentation of Delphi 11 says "Warning: GlobalUseDX10 is deprecated. Please use GlobalUseDX." but GlobalUseDX says that if "false" it will use GDI instead (not DX9)